# How to Display an HTTP Response Body Content-type: application/pdf in a HTML page

Tags: pdf, httpresponse, response-headers

I am getting a HTTP response of the PDF file and I can see the PDF file when I run the API in Postman.

[image]

How to display this response body in a HTML page or download the PDF from HTML Page?

HTML

```
<iframe src="" id="dispwill" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
request.onreadystatechange = () => {
                console.log(request.response);
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status === 200) {
                    console.log(request.getResponseHeader('etag'));
                    console.log(request.responseType);
                    console.log(request.responseURL);
                    const pdfsource = new Blob([request.response],{type: 'application/pdf'});
                    document.getElementById("dispwill").src = pdfsource;

                  }
```

I am trying to get the PDF file itself and display it in a iframe tag but it is not working that way.